# dash inside listview

Tags: android, listview

hello I need to add a dash (-) in an input, if the user puts 4569 display 45-69 or if the user put 568923 display 56-89-23, I use sub string, but it get me and error invalid input,
I use a list view, and List Data. thank you

here is my code:

```
private void showListViewData()
{



    int x = Integer.parseInt(inJugada.getText().toString().substring(0,2)
            + "-" + inJugada.getText().toString().substring(2));
    //int x = Integer.parseInt(inJugada.getText().toString());
    int y = Integer.parseInt(inValor.getText().toString());

    String z = "";
    String zQN = "Qn";
    String zPL = "Pl";  
    String zTR = "Tr";

    inJugada.setText(String.valueOf(x));
    inValor.setText(String.valueOf(y));

   if(String.valueOf(x).length() == 2){
       z = zQN;

   }else if(String.valueOf(x).length() == 4){

       z = zPL;

   }else if(String.valueOf(x).length() == 6){
       z = zTR;
   }


    mData.add(new Data(z, x, y));

    // add new data to list and refresh
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got an error because you try to convert a String into an Integer that cannot be parsed anymore. Take a look at this statement:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(inJugada.getText().toString().substring(0,2)
        + "-" + inJugada.getText().toString().substring(2));
```

Once you add dashes into the String you are not able to parse it into an integer anymore.

Comment: so I have to convert the Int x into string x right, and apply the process

Answer (score 0):

does this work in your case? Once give a try if you are searching for something like this

```
String dummyString yourMainString.substring(0,2);
for(int x = 2;x < yourMainString.length -2 ; x+2)
dummyString = dummyString + "-"+ yourMainString.substring(x,x+2) ; 
dummyString = dummyString + yourMainString.substring(x,yourMainString.length ) ;
```

The dummyString will have a - after two digits